# GitHub git tag without creating zip file?

Tags: github

I'm looking for a way to give users access to data of a specific version of a repo through raw.githubusercontent.com, without massively increasing the size of the already very large repo.

Context: I have a GitHub repo that contains a large amount of data created by a text reuse algorithm.
The same algorithm is run twice a year on a corpus of texts that undergoes change, so the data in this repo changes twice a year.

In order to allow access to a specific version of the text reuse data, I was thinking of using tags; in my understanding, a tag is simply a pointer to a specific commit, so it should not significantly increase the size of the repo.

However, this does not seem to be the case according to an experiment I ran (see below): when I push a tag to GitHub, it also creates a zip file that contains the full data at the time of the commit. It even does this when I have not pushed that commit to GitHub yet, and even if I use the lightweight tag format. It seems that this will increase the size of my GitHub repo enormously.

Is there a way to add tags without the creation of the .zip file?

If not, I was thinking of creating a new branch each time the algorithm is run; the branch would not be updated but only serve as a pointer to that specific commit. Would this increase the size of the repo? Are there other downsides of using a branch for this?

### Experiment:

*Setting up the experiment:*

- Create a test repo and clone it
- create a file in it, with the content "DUMMY DATA – V1"
- add and commit

*Step 1: annotated tag*

- Create an annotated tag: `git tag -a v1.0 -m "First version with dummy data"`
- Push the repo to GitHub: `git push origin main`
- This has pushed only the new file to the repo, not the tag; the tag has to be pushed separately: `git push origin v1.0`
- Now the tag appears on GitHub; it is associated with a zip file that contains the file with content "DUMMY DATA – V1"
- Check whether you can access the file using raw.githubusercontent (it works, after a couple of minutes): https://raw.githubusercontent.com////

*Step 2: annotated tag, push tag first*

- Make changes to the file: change the content to "DUMMY DATA – V2"
- Add and commit the file
- Add a new annotated tag: `git tag -a v2.0 -m "Second version with new dummy data"`
- This time, we'll push the tag before we push the commit: `git push origin v2.0`
- The new tag appears on GitHub, and it is associated with a .zip file that contains the file with contents "DUMMY DATA – V2"; in the repo on GitHub, the file still has the original content "DUMMY DATA – V1"
  => **The zip file is thus not created by GitHub on the server but during the process of pushing the tag!**
- push the commit: `git push origin main`

*Step 3: lightweight tags*

- Make changes to the file: change the content to "DUMMY DATA – V3"
- Add and commit the file
- Create a so-called lightweight tag (omit the "-a" flag, and the message): `git tag v3.0`
- Again, we push the tag before we push the commit: `git push origin v3.0`
- The same thing happens as in step 2: the new tag appears on GitHub, and it is associated with a .zip file that contains the file with contents "DUMMY DATA – V3"; in the repo on GitHub, the file still has the content "DUMMY DATA – V2" => **lightweight tags are not so lightweight: they also create a zip file!**

Answer (score 2):

GitHub provides the ability to download a tarball or zip file, which is automatically generated from the snapshot of a repository at a given state.  These links are automatically provided in the web interface, and these archives are created on demand: if nobody requests them, then they'll never be produced.

When you tag a commit and push the tag but not the branch on which the commit was made, the commit is still pushed.  If you didn't do that, the tag would be dangling and point to a nonexistent commit, and the repository would be corrupt.  Thus, in each case, you're always pushing the commits that are part of the tags.

You can create those archives on your own machine with `git archive`.  For example, if you want to create an archive of v1, you might do `git archive --format=zip -o v1.zip --prefix=v1/ v1.0`.

Comment: Thanks, good to know that the archives are created on demand; I guess that means that the zip files do not increase the repo size on GitHub. I'm still wondering what happens exactly when I push only the tag, not the commit itself, because the contents of the repository as displayed under "code" on GitHub remains unchanged, and on my local machine, git status reports "Your branch is ahead of 'origin/main' by 1 commit".